# Sending more than 700 contacts to server

Tags: android

I'm reading total contacts from my phone directory and sending the total contact list to server. When the list size is below 700, I'm getting the success response but contact list is more than 700 it is showing error like

## Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.

Here is My code

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

         String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

            // get the phone number
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);

            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                mobileNumber = phone;
                mobileNumber = mobileNumber.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");
                ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                numbers.add(mobileNumber);

            }

            pCur.close();
        }
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

here I'm getting the total contacts and how can I separate contacts up to 500 each time and send to server. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a POST request

Comment: I have used POST method and also used Volley and okHttp methods. Still I'm getting errors.

Comment: create one single file of your all contact like 'vcf' or any and then send that single file to your server and extract it.

Comment: the URI has maximum length. You can't exceed it It is not designed to pass so large amount of data. Use POST request for your task. `Still I'm getting errors` means that you do something wrong.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: This is the code I have used but it is showing same error.

Comment: @BhaveshRangani can you please give me the code to convert the list of contacts to 'vcf' file.